# Adding all file paths from a folder to String array

Tags: android

I am trying to generate an array with each item in the array being the path of a video located in a folder named raw in resources. However the program crashes when it is run. Here is the code for adding the file names to a String array.

```
        String[] fileArray;
        File dir = new File("/res/raw");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        fileArray = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i){
            fileArray[i] = files[i].getName();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
        String name = fields[i].getName();
        //do your thing here

    }
```

Comment: what does fields contain?

Comment: @Huhtamaki all files exist inside `raw` folder

Comment: ah yea. Thank you